# I am Unable to Navigate to the Home Page Even after successful login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, authentication, react-router-dom

Below are the codes for simple login, but even after successful login the navigation is not working. I am unable to resolve this

login.js

```
import './Login.css'
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Login() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
   
  const [username, setusername] = useState('');
  const [password, setpassword] = useState('');

  const handleApi = () => {
    console.log({ username, password });

    const url = 'http://localhost:4000/login';
    const data = { username, password };

    axios.post(url, data)
      .then((res) => {  
        console.log(res.data);
        if (res.data.message) {
          alert(res.data.message);
          if (res.data.token) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
            navigate('/');
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        alert("SERVER ERROR");
      })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <h1>LOGIN</h1>

        <form>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter your Email ID"
            value={username}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setusername(e.target.value)
            }}
            required
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter your Password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setpassword(e.target.value)
            }}
            required
          />
          <button className="btn" onClick={handleApi}>LOGIN</button>
          <p>Not Having An Account <Link to="/signup">Signup</Link></p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login;
```

This is my index.js file where route is defined. I am unable to figure out the where the problem is happening.

```
import './index.css';
import * as React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider
  // Route,
  // Link,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './components/Home.jsx';
import Login from './components/Login/Login.jsx';
import Signup from './components/Signup/Signup.jsx';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home />,
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    element: <div>About</div>,
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login />,
  },
  {
    path: "/signup",
    element: <Signup />,
  },
]);

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

This is my backend code

```js
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const port = 4000

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/sparebazar").then(()=>{
    console.log("mongoose connected ")
}).catch((e)=>{
 console.log("not connected" )
 console.log(e)
})
const Users = mongoose.model('Users', { username: String, password: String });

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;


  const user = new Users({ username: username, password: password });
  user.save()
    .then(() => {
      res.send({ message: 'saved successfully' })
    })
    .catch(() => {
      res.send({ message: 'server error' })
    })
})

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  // console.log(req.body);

  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  Users.findOne({ username: username })
    .then((result) => {
      // console.log(result, " user data");
      if (!result) {
        console.log( " user not found");
        res.send({ message: 'User Not Found' });
      }
      else {
        if (result.password == password) {
          const token = jwt.sign({
            data: result
          }, 'MYKEY', { expiresIn: 60 });
          console.log(result," user data is correct ");
          res.send({ message: 'Find successfully', token: token })
        }
        if (result.password != password) {
          console.log(" password data is wrong ");
          res.send({ message: 'Password is Wrong' })
        }
      }

    })
    .catch(() => {
      res.send({ message: 'server error' })
    })
})
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easy to use `useHistory`.

```
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
...
//const navigate = useNavigate()
const history = useHistory();
...
if (res.data.token) {
  localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
  //navigate('/');
  history.push('/')
}
```

I hope this answer can help you.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Your `Login` component is submitting the `form` element and isn't preventing the default form submission from occurring, which is reloading the page on the current route. `button` elements are `type="submit"` by default, so this is why the form is submitted.

## Solutions

- Specify that the "LOGIN" button is a `type="button"` explicitly, so when clicked it doesn't submit the form.

  ```
  <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={handleApi}>
    LOGIN
  </button>
  ```
- Specify that the "LOGIN" button is a `type="submit"` explicitly, and move the `handleApo` callback to the `form` element's `onSubmit` handler and prevent the default form action.

  ```
  function Login() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [username, setusername] = useState("");
    const [password, setpassword] = useState("");

    const handleApi = (e) => { // <-- consume submit event object
      e.preventDefault();      // <-- prevent default form action

      console.log({ username, password });

      const url = "http://localhost:4000/login";
      const data = { username, password };

      axios
        .post(url, data)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
          if (res.data.message) {
            alert(res.data.message);
            if (res.data.token) {
              localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token);
              navigate("/");
            }
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          alert("SERVER ERROR");
        });
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <h1>LOGIN</h1>

          <form onSubmit={handleApi}> // <-- use onSubmit handler
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter your Email ID"
              value={username}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setusername(e.target.value);
              }}
              required
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter your Password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setpassword(e.target.value);
              }}
              required
            />
            <button type="submit" className="btn"> // <-- submit button type
              LOGIN
            </button>
            <p>
              Not Having An Account <Link to="/signup">Signup</Link>
            </p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  ```

While the first is the *easier* fix, it ***doesn't*** prevent the submission of the `form` element completely. For this reason the second solution would/should be the more correct fix.